# Does 1 Kings 11:28 refer voluntary workers, oppressed laborers, conscripts, slaves or what?

Tags: translation-philosophy, solomon, slavery

Here are a few translations of the verse in question:

- AMP - The man Jeroboam was a brave warrior and when Solomon saw that the young man was industrious, he put him in charge of all the forced labor of the house of Joseph.
- CSB - Now the man Jeroboam was capable, and Solomon noticed the young man because he was getting things done. So he appointed him over the entire labor force of the house of Joseph.
- DARBY - ... Solomon saw the young man that he was industrious, and he made him ruler over all the charge of the house of Joseph.
- DRA - ... made him chief over the tributes of all the house of Joseph.
- EASY -  he made Jeroboam the leader of the workers who belonged to Joseph's tribe.
- EHV -  he appointed him over all the forced labor of the house of Joseph.
- KJV -  he made him ruler over all the charge of the house of Joseph.
- NABRE - he put him in charge of all the carriers conscripted from the house of Joseph.

In the most basic sense translators are divided over whether these workers were involved in forced/conscripted labor or simply "labor." Is the text ambiguous here? Are there textual variants that would lead one translation to interpret the labor as forced while the other omits the term? Are some translators whitewashing Solomon's treatment of the northern tribes? Are others presuming the labor was forced because of what is said in the next chapter, indicating that the laborers felt oppressed?

1 Kings 12

> Then Jeroboam and the whole assembly of Israel came and they said to
> Rehoboam, 4 “Your father [Solomon] put a heavy yoke on us. If you now lighten
> the harsh servitude and the heavy yoke your father imposed on us, we
> will be your servants.”

To restate the basic question: does 1 Kings 11:28 actually say "forced labor?" as opposed to "labor?" Should we picture these workers as voluntary, oppressed, legally conscripted, enslaved, or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my very literal translation of 1 Kings 11:28 -

> And the man, Jeroboam, was mighty and strong; and Solomon, seeing that
> the young man was diligent and industrious, made him supervisor over all
> work of the house of Joseph.

The two significant words here bout which the OP enquires are:

- פְקַד (paqad) = " to attend to, visit, muster, appoint" which I translated "supervisor" above.
- סֵבֶל (sebel) = "a load, burden" which might be translated (in this context) labor force", or "work".  It also occurs in Neh 4:17, Ps 81:6 where it translated "burden".

Thus, there is no explicit mention here of "forced labor" or "slavery", etc.  It simply says that Jeroboam was placed in charge of all burdens/work.  The text does not even explicitly refer to people, although that is implied as those who do the work.

Comment: I upvoted both answers so far... and accepted this one because it deals directly with the issue of "forced" in the text.

Answer (score 1):

David had his own officer,named Adoram, in charge of "forced labour" (2 Samuel ch20 v24). I would add the testimony in 1 Kings ch9 vv20-22 that Solomon built the temple by means of a "forced levy of slaves" drawn from the surviving Canaanites of the land, and that the Israelites themselves were exempt.

From the perspective of an old student of history, I would be inclined to call the forced labour "oppression", delivered grudgingly and enforced by authority rather than law. The kind of thing Samuel warned them about in 1 Samuel ch8.

The distinction between the forced labour to which they were subjected, and the slavery from which they were exempt, was probably a fine line, based perhaps on shorter terms of service. The reaction in ch12 suggests that the house of Joseph could not see much difference.

Comment: It was a question about 1Sam8 that prompted me to ask this.